# How to clear specific marker with gmap3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I got a simple code that generate 10 different marker, actually i use :

`$("#test").gmap3(
                {action:'addMarker', name:'marker', latLng: (my lat & lng value)},
                ... (10 times)
});`

In order to clear my marker i user `{action:'clear', name:'marker'}` but it remove my all 10 markers!

How can i tell Gmap3 to remove a specific marker?

I have see i can add a tag to my marker like :

`{action:'addMarker', name:'marker', latLng: (my lat & lng value), tag : "mytag"}`

but then when i put :

`{action:'clear', name:'marker', tag : "mytag"}`

it doen't remove my specific tagged marker

any idea?

thank's a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, i don't know why but Tag works perfectly well like this for exemple :

```
    `<script type="text/javascript">                

        $(function(){
            $("#putain").gmap3();
                $("#putain").gmap3({action:'addMarker', name:'marker', address: "paris", tag : "mytag-paris"});
                $("#putain").gmap3({action:'addMarker', name:'marker', address: "new york", tag : "mytag-newyork"});
                $("#putain").gmap3({action:'clear', name:'marker', tag:'mytag-paris'});         
        });

    </script>
```

`

in that case it remove specificaly the tagged "mytag-paris" marker and don't remove the tagged "tag-newyork" marker

Answer (score 0):

I would expect if you gave each marker a unique **name**, then when you call the 'clear' action, using that unique **name** would remove just the one you want to.

Comment: Hello, and thank's for your answers, but like i said, when i try to add a 'tag: "my-tag-name"' to a marker and then use the clear action like i put : {action:'clear', name:'marker', tag : "my-tag-name"} it doesn't clear my tagged marker.

In the documentation of gmap3 there is a exemple of using tags... but it's hard to understand how it work...

When i google {action:'clear', name:'marker', tag : "mytag"} i doens't get any good answers, that's why i think i use a wrong technique...

Comment: I'm talking about using the name attribute, not the tag attribute

Comment: the name attribute? something like : 
{action:'addMarker', name:'my-name', latLng: (my lat & lng value)}

and then 

{action:'clear', name:'my-name'}

??

Comment: It doesn't work, for exemple this code :

`    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
          
          $("#test").gmap3();

$('#test').gmap3(
    {
        action: 'addMarker',
 name: "wahou",
        address: "place de l'étoile, paris",
    }
);


$('#test').gmap3(
    {
        action: 'clear',
 name: "wahou"
    }
);



          
      });
    </script>`

Is not working, i still got my marker, that should be erease.

But the code work if i put name: "marker", instead of name: "wahou"

Comment: if i put {action:'clear', name:'marker'}, then my marker is cleared but all the marker are... and i still stuck into my problem, where i want to clear only a selected marker not all of them...

Comment: As tell here : http://gmap3.net/api/clear.html it seems that's the way to clear a specified object is the use of Tag...

Comment: Yeah I was wrong; your original code with the tag should be fine apparently, so I'm at a loss for any more suggestions

Comment: Still, it doesn't work with tag.. and my question stay without answers!

Thank's anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and utilizing your clue I found out what the issue was for me.

In my case the problem was in addMarker logic. In my case query:

```
{action:'addMarker', name:'marker', latLng: (my lat & lng value), tag : "mytag"}
```

worked perfectly.

However, when there was a map property in action, the gmap3 would fail to write tag to the marker. e.g:

```
{action:'addMarker', name:'marker',map:{center:true}, latLng: (my lat & lng value), tag : "mytag"}
```

In this case, gmap3 fails to copy the tag. I am not sure whether this is a bug or a feature.

This error happens within `getObject()` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old post but in case someone is looking...  I would simply use just the tag and leave out the name reference for removing one marker.  Like this.

```
{action:'clear',tag:'my-tag-name'}
```